# Error connecting to Atlas MongoDB with Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to atlas mongo db using node js. But getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of null` I have created the cluster at atlas and given complete rights to user *aayushg* and also created a db 'test'

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser') 
const app = express()  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// replace the uri string with your connection string.
const url = "mongodb+srv://aayushg:<aayushg18>@cluster0-fatp8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect((err, database) => {
 db = database.db("test")
 app.listen(3000, function () {
 })
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
       //res.send('PDP')
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')   
    })
  app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => { 
      db.collection('devices').save(req.body, (err, result) => {
         if (err) return console.log(err)
         console.log('saved to database')
         res.redirect('/')
       })
    })
})
```

**SCREENSHOT OF CMD**
[image]

Comment: please add your terminal screen shot too

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: I think you have no client

Comment: i tried with using client also but didnt work

Comment: i have updated my code

Comment: so now it is working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201642/discussion-between-pardeep-and-aayush-gupta).

Comment: Your DB is not connected yet. Is there any error before 'connecting...' ? If there, please give the full screenshot. If your DB is connected properly then you will not get this error whatever your collection is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the error was related to the credentials you are providing with the help of `if(err) throw err` you can see the error is regarding the credentials. Now, you have to add correct credentials it will work fine. you are using `<aayushg18>` instead of `aayushg18` Thanks.

Comment: The error is in this line `db = database.db("test")` here `database`is null, there is problem in connection. But your answer states that problem lies `if (err) return console.log(err)` before that itself error in thrown.

Comment: nope there is error in credentials we have go through the chat :)

Comment: I have just updated my last line to make you understand, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have got your problem. You connection uri is not in correct format. Do not use  <> sign when you input your password. Replace `<aayushg18>` by `aayushg18` like following:

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://aayushg:aayushg18@cluster0-fatp8.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```